# order of $\mathbb{Z}_3^*/(\mathbb{Z}_3^*)^3$

Tags: group-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I would like to know what is the order of $\mathbb{Z}_3^*/(\mathbb{Z}_3^*)^3$ as a group, where $\mathbb{Z}_3$ represents the 3-adic integers.

I know how to find the units of $\mathbb{Z}_3$, but I do not know how to compute its cube. Please help me with this.